# fetch data of same date in one column another date data in another column

Tags: php, mysql

Here is table..

```
id|  date      |  age|  location|  place
1   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
2   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
3   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
4   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
5   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
6   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
7   2014-10-25    18      abc       xyz
8   2014-10-25    18      abc       xyz
```

i want result as(select one date data in one column one row another date data in another column another row ) shown below:-

```
1   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
2   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
3   2014-10-20    18      abc       xyz
```

---

```
4   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
5   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
6   2014-10-24    18      abc       xyz
```

---

```
7   2014-10-25    18      abc       xyz
8   2014-10-25    18      abc       xyz
```

Comment: if you have to only select ids you can use sql IN clause: WHERE id IN (1,4,7)

Comment: i want to fetch data according to date wise.... where date>=date("Y-m-d");    :-----fetch same date data in one column and another date data in another column

Comment: if you don't know dates , but you want to get dates from this table you can to SELECT date FROM table GROUP BY date. So you have dates,then you can select rows  for each DATE.

Comment: can u provide the query::;

Answer (score 0):

I write here, in comment would't be clear.

```
//GET  DISTINCTS DATES
select date from table group by date
```

query rows fetched of first query

```
    foreach($rows as $value){

$data=$value['date'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date>='$data' ORDER BY id ASC";



//query and fetch ,THEN save into array 
    //or print as you like




}
```

Comment: <?php 
 $curdate=date("Y-m-d");
$city='berlin';
$sqlT = "SELECT date FROM ".$city." WHERE date >= '".$curdate."' GROUP BY date ";
$sh=mysql_query($sqlT);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_row($sh))
{
?>
 <html>
 <body>
 <table>
<?PHP
$qqq="SELECT event_id,date,age,time,location,place FROM ".$city." WHERE date >= '".$row1[0]."' ORDER BY date ";
$rs=mysql_query($qqq);

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
  ?>

 <tr><td><?php echo $row[0]?></td><td><?php echo $row[1]?></td><td><?php echo $row[2]?></td><td><?php echo $row[3]?></td></tr>
 
 <?php
 
 }?>
 </table>
 <BR><HR>
 <?PHP
 }?>
 
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: confused but seems to be ok

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP_CONCAT() 
select date,GROUP_CONCAT(place) from table group by date